# Trying to get property 'full_time' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

i have two tables, `employees table` and `payrolls table`, now am trying to add data into `payrolls table` to calculate the gross amount for an employee, but when ever i try to do so i keep on getting that error, can someone help me figure this out!

**Here is** `Payroll model` `

```
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

protected $fillable = ['over_time', 'notified','hours','rate', 'gross', 'employee_id'];

public function employee(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
}

public function grossPay(){
    $calc = 0;
    if($this->employee->full_time && !$this->over_time){
        return $this->gross = $this->employee->role->salary;
    }
    if($this->employee->full_time && $this->over_time){
        $calc = $this->hours * $this->rate;
        return $this->gross = $calc + $this->employee->role->salary;
    }
    if($this->over_time || !$this->employee->full_time){
        $calc = $this->hours * $this->rate;
        return $this->gross = $calc;
    }
    return $this->$gross = 0;
}
```

}`

**Here is the route:**
`Route::post('/payrolls/{id}', 'PayrollController@store')->name('payrolls.store');`

**PayrollController**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request ,[
        'over_time' => 'required|bool',
        'hours' => 'required',
        'rate' => 'required'
    ]);

    $payroll = new Payroll;
    $payroll->over_time = $request->over_time;
    $payroll->hours = $request->hours;
    $payroll->rate = $request->rate;
    $payroll->employee_id = $request->employee_id;
    $payroll->grossPay();
    $payroll->save();

    return redirect('payroll.show', ['employee_id'=>$employee_id] )->with('success','payroll created');

}
```

Comment: here is `PayRollController` function to post data to  `payroll table`

Comment: `employee` column exists in the 'payroll' table?

Comment: i have `employee_id` in `payroll` table

Comment: You can not access the `$this->employee` directly because it is a payroll model. So you should find an employee first.

Comment: So i should add `Employee::find($id)` in payroll `store function`?

Comment: I have solved it. i was supped to pass in `id` to payroll `store function`! thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You should find an employee and then check the appropriate condition.

```
public function grossPay(){
    $calc = 0;
    $employee = Employee::findOrFail($this->employee_id);

    if($employee->full_time && !$this->over_time){
        return $this->gross = $this->employee->role->salary;
    }
    if($employee->full_time && $this->over_time){
        $calc = $this->hours * $this->rate;
        return $this->gross = $calc + $employee->role->salary;
    }
    if($this->over_time || !$this->full_time){
        $calc = $this->hours * $this->rate;
        return $this->gross = $calc;
    }
    return $this->gross = 0;
  }
```